# Install crossbuild-essential-armhf on amd64

Tags: arm, cross-compilation

Right now, while working on my laptop (amd64), I can already compile code through SSH on a BeagleBone (armhf).

What I'm trying to do now, is being able to use any IDE to debug that code (Code::Blocks, KDevelop, or Qt Creator).

So, I thought of running `gdbserver` on the BeagleBone, and connecting to it, but it gives me an error of unexpected value on reply. I read about it, and it seems I need to locally build an armhf executable, for `gdb` to process. But I guess it also needs an armhf-oriented `gdb` built for amd64, so I tried installing `crossbuild-essential-armhf`. For that, I added the armhf architecture with `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`, but then I'm unable to do an apt-get update. I get a whole lot of these:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main armhf Packages             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::13 80]
```

If I check the repos, they indeed do not have armhf anywhere.

So, what am I doing wrong? Also, is this the correct way to remote debug with a different architecture, or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu uses separate repos for armh (i.e. `http://ports.ubuntu.com/`).
To be able to install crossbuild-essential-armhf successfully you have to follow these steps:

1. run `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
2. specify the correct architecture for ALL your apt deb lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, for example:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
   deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty main universe
   ```

Note that it does not make sense to specify the arch for deb-src lines.
3. run `apt-get update`
4. run `apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf`

Have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

You may also want to execute these commands in a chroot (or docker container maybe) as mentioned by this guide: [Getting Started with MultiArch (armel / armhf) in Ubuntu](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/05/02/getting-started-with-multiarch-armel-armhf-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a rich choice of Docker based cross compilers here :

https://github.com/dockcross/dockcross

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to add armhf to the build host's dpkg sources. Another approach is to use a chroot which can be populated using debootstrap or from a beagleboard.org image.

For a thorough guide on C++ cross-compilation with remote GDB symbolic debugging with VS Code see:

https://takeofftechnical.com/x-compile-cpp-bbb